# Converting a collection to an object[]

Tags: c#, reflection, collections

I've been looking for a way to move the items of a collection (I haven't decided on what sort of collection) to an `Object[]`. I'm attempting to invoke a method through reflection using a the calling method's parameter (the collection) as the invoked method's parameters.

I have a couple (UPDATE) of methods that I wish to access through a REST api that in turn requires different amounts of parameters. As such I've decided to use a collection as one of the parameters that the REST api's `Update` requires. 
But since I need to invoke a method from reflection I also need to somehow parse / cast the collection to an `Object[]` somehow.

This is what I have right now, and as mentioned I seem to be a bit stuck...

Also, please keep in mind that this is not a question on how to set up the REST service (like my other), but simply how to best cast the collection to the correct invoke parameters. Additionally any help or advice on what sort of collection to use would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void Update(String proc, List<String> parameters)
{
    var myType = typeof(JaberoDC.JaberoDC.JaberoDC);
    var list = parameters;
    var method = myType
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
        .Single(mi => string.Equals(mi.Name, proc, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    var subject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
    var result = method.Invoke(subject, list);
}
```

Here are two examples of methods that I intend to invoke:

```
public bool UPDATEActivities(int? iID, int? iWorksiteID, string strActivityName, string strMethodOfWork, DateTime? dtPlannedStart, DateTime? dtActualStart, DateTime? dtPlannedFinish, DateTime? dtActualFinish, bool? blMileStoneFlag, bool? blActivityCutShort, int? iInterruptionMinutes, string strVarianceReason, string strConn, string strUserName);

public bool UPDATEWorksiteEntry(int? iID, string strJobName, string strJobID, string strSiteName, int? iCalendarWeek, int? iMainContractor, string strJobStartFrom, string strJobEndAt, string strSACStaffAssigned, string strReferenceNumber, int? iTerritory, string strFunction, string strItemNumber, string strLine, int? iWorksiteType, string strUID, string strEventNumber, string strRestrictions, string strLatitude, string strLongitude, string strPlannedWork, int? iPlannedStartMileage, int? iPlannedFinishMileage, DateTime? dtPlannedStart, DateTime? dtActualstart, DateTime? dtPlannedFinish, DateTime? dtActualFinish, int? iActualFinishMileage, int? iActualFinishYardage, int? iActualStartMileage, int? iActualStartYardage, int? iPlannedFinishYardage, int? iPlannedStartYardage, string strSACDayPhoneNo, string strSACNightPhoneNo, string strELR, string strSacPoint, bool? blTunnelSignIn, string strConn, string strUserName);
```

Comment: What is the question and where is your current problem in the posted code?

Comment: Oh, thought it was obvious. I'm basically delirious having looked at the same code for a few hours. 
Basically I'm not sure how to invoke the method with the elements in the list (parameters) as the invoked method's parameters.

Comment: Also, thanks for the edit, servy. :)

Comment: Note that you can't pass all arguments to your `UPDATEWorksiteEntry` method as `List<string>` (as `int?` is not exactly string)

Comment: Yeah, know that. Thought that I'd cross that bridge when I get to it. Any advice on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need `object[]` as for list of arguments for `Invoke` - calling `ToArray` on `IEnumerable<object>` is one option<sup>*</sup>:

```
   List<string> parameters = new List<string>{"a","b"};
   var paramsAsObjects = parameters
        .Cast<object>() // need to cast each item from string to object
        .ToArray();

   methodWithTwoStringParam.Invoke(..., paramsAsObjects);
```

---

<sup>*</sup>Note: `Invoke` requires types of items in arrays to match types of parameters. Casting to `object` does not change type of parameter. If methods you need to call take different types as arguments (i.e. not all `string`) than you'd need to stick with passing arguments to your helper as collection of base types of all possible parameters. Most likely you endup with collection of `object` elements - like `List<object>` or just avoid all conversions and construct `object[]` to start with.

If your values start from untyped strings (i.e. user input) you may consider using [Convert.ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Cast` to try to match parameter types. `ChangeType` works for string to numeric types conversions, if you need more complicated types - use your own conversion logic.

Comment: Would this cast the individual elements of the collection (list<string> parameters) to a object[] with the elements in them?
Meaning if parameters was ["1","2", "3"] then paramAsObjects would be ["1","2", "3"]?

Comment: @geostocker yes. Note that casting to object does not change type of parameters - so you can't pass `string` as `int` parameter anyway.

Comment: @Alexei: So... your answer is correct on a technical level, but on a functional level it will totally fail: He will get a beautiyfull exception...

Comment: @MartinMulder care to explain? OP knows that argument types need to match, so what other cases you are hinting at?

Comment: @Alexei: Yes, he knows. And he asks how (quote: "...how to best cast the collection to the correct invoke parameters."). You put the strings from the list to an object-array, but they are still strings, and not the required `int`, `DateTime`, etc.